# How do I make [container>ul>li>a] take the full height of the [container]

Tags: css, tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I make `container>ul>li>a` take the full height of the `container`?

http://www.bootply.com/119627

I do not want to set it with height unless 100%

Comment: `container>ul>li>a{ height: 100% }` ?

Comment: Set the line-height = to the container's height?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in CSS3, but support is still an issue on older browsers. You can use flexbox, but you'll want to add a javascript fallback if you need to support older browsers... See http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/